# Python/Bash - send alert when program crashes

Tags: python, bash, vps

I have a Python program which runs on the AWS (VPS). It is still in development stage so obviously errors occurs...sometimes after few hours and sometimes after a few days. Constantly checking if it still runs is kind of annoying tho.

Is there any smart way to make it send me an alert (email, sms or something) when it crashes?

The program is made from many files and uses few libraries, so I think it may be smarter to make some bash script that catches errors. Yet I have no idea where to start.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you already sent an email on the command line to check if you can reach a mail server and if it is configured correctly?

Comment: What have you already tried? And what part of the solution are you stuck on? How to write the Bash script? How to send the alert back home? Or are you looking for a better way to send notifications when your program crashes on AWS? For the last one, [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_cwet2.html) might be a good place to start.

Comment: You can log each step of the program and make another program that will check this log permanently.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a simple "healtheck" api that responds successfully if your application is alive.  Then periodically call that api from another program that can send a notification.

Or if you want something a bit more robust, you can use AWS route 53 [healthchecks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html).

Answer (score 1):

Why not integrate [Sentry](https://sentry.io/) for error tracking?

The docs for integrating the python sdk are [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/).